# python/numpy generated binary file to be read by C

Tags: python, c, numpy, io, binary

I am creating a 5*7 integer matrix binary file in python called random_from_python_int.dat, I then read this binary file from C. Somehow I can not get the correct numbers
Here is my python code to generate this matrix:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
filename = "random_from_python_int.dat"
fileobj = open(filename, mode='wb')
b = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,7))
b.tofile(fileobj)
fileobj.close
```

this will generate a matrix

```
[ [  9 15 64 28 89 93 29]
  [  8 73 0  40 36 16 11]
  [ 54 88 62 33 72 78 49]
  [ 51 54 77 69 13 25 13]
  [ 92 86 30 30 89 12 65] ]
```

But when I read it from the C code from below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
  /* later changed 'double' to 'int', but that still had issues */
  double randn[5][7];

  char buff[256];
  FILE *latfile;

  sprintf(buff,"%s","random_from_python_int.dat");
  latfile=fopen(buff,"r");
  fread(&(randn[0][0]),sizeof(int),35,latfile);
  fclose(latfile);
  printf("\n %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d",randn[0][0],randn[0][1],randn[0][2],randn[0][3],randn[0][4],randn[0][5],randn[0][6]);
  printf("\n %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d",randn[1][0],randn[1][1],randn[1][2],randn[1][3],randn[1][4],randn[1][5],randn[1][6]);
  printf("\n %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d",randn[2][0],randn[2][1],randn[2][2],randn[2][3],randn[2][4],randn[2][5],randn[2][6]);
  printf("\n %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d",randn[3][0],randn[3][1],randn[3][2],randn[3][3],randn[3][4],randn[3][5],randn[3][6]);
  printf("\n %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d     %d\n",randn[4][0],randn[4][1],randn[4][2],randn[4][3],randn[4][4],randn[4][5],randn[4][6]);
}
```

It will give me (adjusted for spaces to avoid scrolling on the stackoverflow site):

```
      28      15         64      93         29 -163754450   9
      40      73          0      16         11 -163754450   8
      33      88         62      17         91 -163754450  54
     256       0 1830354560       0    4196011 -163754450 119
 4197424 4197493 1826683808 4196128 2084711472 -163754450  12
```

I am not sure what is wrong. I have tried this writing a float matrix in python and read it as double in C, it works fine. But this integer matrix just does not work.

Comment: You read integers into doubles.

Comment: So after the integer vs. double confusion, the remaining question is: How do you know that the "integer" numpy writes is the same size as the "int" C uses?

Comment: Oops! But after I changed the double to int, I got  9     0     15     0     64     0     28
 0     89     0     93     0     29     0
 8     0     73     0     0     0     40
 0     36     0     16     0     11     0
 54     0     88     0     62     0     33.

Comment: There are zeros mixed in the data. I dont know where they come from

Comment: "*How do you know that the "integer" numpy writes is the same size as the "int" C uses*" - that's a very good thought. You can maybe google it. In C you can force a size by using the types int32_t, int64_t

Comment: Step 1: `latfile=fopen(buff,"r");` --> `latfile=fopen(buff,"rb");`  (Add `b`)

Comment: What is the size of file `random_from_python_int.dat`?

Comment: Apparently, you can give the desired integer size to `numpy.random.randint` as the optional `dtype` parameter. Default is `np.int` (whatever that may be in C), but explicit integer sizes 32 and 64 are also available which can be combined with explicit integer sizes 32 and 64 in C easily.

Comment: And if you want to use a specific C type as the type for your values in numpy, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html has a list of supported types many of which directly relate to C types.

Answer (score 6):

As @tdube writes, the quick summary of your issue is: Your `numpy` implementation writes 64bit integers, while your C code reads 32bit integers.

As for some more details, read on.

When you write and read integers as two's complement binary data, you need to make certain that the following three integer properties are the same for both the producer and the consumer of the binary data: integer **size**, integer **endianness**, integer **signedness**.

The **signedness** is *signed* for both numpy and C, so we have a match here.

The **endianness** is not an issue here because both numpy and the C program are on the *same machine*, and thus you probably have the *same endianness* (regardless of what endianness it might actually be).

However, the **size** is the issue.

By default, [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) uses `np.int` as its `dtype`. `np.int` is of unknown size from the documentation but turns out to be 64 bits on your system.

The [numpy scalars reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html) lists a few integer types (remarkably not including `np.int`), of which three combinations are interesting for robustly interfacing with programs outside of `numpy`:

```
 # | numpy    | C
---+----------+---------
 1 | np.int32 | int32_t
 2 | np.int64 | int64_t
 3 | np.intc  | int
```

If you only happen to interface your `numpy` based software to the same C environment used to build `numpy`, using the (`np.intc`, `int`) pair of types (from case `3`) looks safe.

However, I would strongly prefer one of the explicitly sized types (cases `1` and `2`) for the following reasons:

- It is absolutely obvious what size the integer is in both `numpy` and C.
- You can thus use your `numpy` generated output to interface to a program compiled with a different C environment which may have a different size `int`.
- You can even use your `numpy` generated output to interface to a program written in a completely different language or compiled for and running on a completely different machine. You have to consider endianness for the different machine scenario, though.

Comment: np.int is not a numpy type. It's just a confusing alias for the built-in python `int` that it's too late to remove.

Comment: The facts are: `np.int` is not documented in the numpy scalars reference, but `numpy.random.randint` is documented to use `np.int` as the default type. Amend the docs maybe?

Comment: That&#39;s a mistake in the randint docs, which I think I fixed recently in master. `np.int` shouldn't be on the numpy scalar page as it is not one - but perhaps there should be a warning there that explicitly says that. (And for np.float, np.complex, ...)

Comment: Good catch. Seems I missed the pyx files in [#9517](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9517)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152976/discussion-between-ndim-and-eric).

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer

Your Python program outputs 64-bit integers, not 32-bit integers which you are trying to read with your C program.

You can change the following line of code:

```
b = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,7), dtype=np.int32)
```

Now you will see 32-bit integers in the output file.

### How to Tell What Your Python Code Outputs

Your Python code dumps 64-bit integers based on the following analysis of a `hexdump` of your output file. Of course, you can examine the binary data file with any hex editor application.

```
$ hexdump random_from_python_int.dat
0000000 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000010 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000020 59 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

As @ndim points out in his answer, two's complement integer representation consists of three major elements: [*storage*] *size*, *endianness* and *signedness*. I will not repeat information which he provides in his answer except to show how to deduce those from the above output which was what I started to do in my original answer.

In your case of multi-dimensional arrays, you may also need to know the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) of elements in linear storage.

#### Deducing Integer Storage Size

Since you indirectly specify the maximum non-inclusive random value of (decimal) `100` from `np.random.randint()`, your values will be in the decimal range `[0, 100)`, or `[0x0, 0x64)` in hexadecimal which can all be represented in a single "hex byte". Note that none of the non-`00` hex bytes in the above `hexdump` outputs are outside this range.  As you can see, there are a total of 8 bytes used to represent each integer value (1 non-`00`-byte and 7 `00`-bytes based on the range of numbers in this case).

#### Deducing Endianness

Furthermore, you also now can deduce the *endianness* of the integer representation, which is *[little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)* in this case as the *[least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)* (LSB) is part of the first byte in linear storage. The LSB may also be referred to as the *least signficant byte*.

#### Deducing Signedness

In this case, you cannot deduce signedness, because you have no negative values in your sampling. If you did, in two's complement representation, you would see a value of `1` for the *signed bit*. I won't delve into the details of two's complement negative integer representation, which would be off-topic for this question.

#### Deducing Multi-dimensional Array Order

An examination of the first two 8-byte, little endian integers in the above output starting at file offset (`0x`) `0000000` (and `0000008` which is not labeled) are hexadecimal values `0x00000000 00000009` and `0x00000000 0000000f`, which are the decimal values of `9` and `15` respectively. The decimal value `9` would be the first value in either *[row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)* or *column-major order*, but the second decimal value in linear storage being `15` indicates row-major ordering as the *row* elements are in contiguous storage.

The hexadecimal value of the third integer's value located at file offset (`0x`) `0000010` is `0x00000000 00000040` which in decimal is the numeric value `64`. This value is the third value in your expected output in *row-major order*.

For completeness, column-major order would output the decimal value of `8` as the second integer represented in linear storage.

### How to Make Numpy Dump 32-bit Numbers in Your Python Code

To make your code dump 32-bit numbers, which is a common implementation length of `int` (but it is "implementation defined" in the C standard which only specifies a minimum range for `int` to represent), you can change the following line of code:

```
b = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,7), dtype=np.int32)
```

Now you will see 32-bit integers in the output file.

```
$ hexdump random_from_python_int.dat
0000000 09 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00
0000010 59 00 00 00 5d 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 08 00 00 00
0000020 49 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 24 00 00 00
```

NOTE: The actual storage size (precision) of C `int` variables is "implementation defined", which means you may need to adjust the `numpy` array integer storage size before output for maximum compatibility with C. See @ndim's excellent answer that provides more detail regarding this.

### Changes to Your C Code

Your C code must be updated to reflect the change in data types for the two-dimensional array. In your code, `double randn[5][7]` should be `int randn[5][7]`. You could also make the type `int32_t` as @ndim pointed out, but your compiler may issue an error and suggest the data type `__int32_t` (which is a `typedef` for `int` on my system). After making that change and compililing, I get the following output:

```
 9     15     64     28     89     93     29
 8     73     0     40     36     16     11
 54     88     62     33     72     78     49
 51     54     77     69     13     25     13
 92     86     30     30     89     12     65
```

#### UPDATE (See also UPDATE #2)

Per @ndim's comment below, you can also use `np.intc` as below. <s>This option is likely the best option unless you are targeting a specific storage size for integer representation.</s>

```
b = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,7), dtype=np.intc)
```

I tested this and it also produces 32-bit integers as well.

#### UPDATE #2

I totally agree with @ndim that specifying the integer size is best for maximizing compatibility. The Python idiom of "least surprise" applies here.

Comment: According to the numpy docs, `np.intc` will use and write to the file in numpy whatever C sees as an `int`.